# How to re execute failed automation scenarios from Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber, testng

I am running cucumber tests in the TestNG framework using the maven command. Daily I am executing the test cases from Jenkins and generating the cucumber report in Jenkins.  (using cucumber report plugin)

I am looking for a solution to re-run the failed test cases in Jenkins and it should give the final report.

Please provide me the approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

On of the simple way is, use IRetryAnalyzer in TestNG. It will re-run the failed test case.

In final report if re-run passed then i will display as passed (initially failed one display as skipped)

if re-run also failed, then marked as failure.

example:

```
 public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer {

private int count = 0;
private static int maxTry = 3;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    if (!iTestResult.isSuccess()) {                      //Check if test not succeed
        if (count < maxTry) {                            //Check if maxtry count is reached
            count++;                                     //Increase the maxTry count by 1
            iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);  //Mark test as failed
            return true;                                 //Tells TestNG to re-run the test
        } else {
            iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);  //If maxCount reached,test marked as failed
        }
    } else {
        iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);      //If test passes, TestNG marks it as passed
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Add in Testng.xml file

You can add test to also

```
 @Test(retryAnalyzer = Retry.class)
```

Comment: Thank you for the details. Here I am not generating the testng.xml file. here we are generating the cucumber.json file as a test result. This file is used to generate the report. I am using testrunner class to execute the test cases.  Is this solution work for the same.